# Pause/Resume Messages

Tags: spring-integration, spring-xd

I am looking for suggestions to implement a message pause/resume pattern on spring-xd/integration platform. I need to be able to park a set of messages and then resume them based on some user driven input. I need more fine grain control vs. just shutting down an endpoint programmatically via ControlBus for example.

I looked at the Delayer endpoint and that would work to enable pausing messages on the fly based on some business logic. What I am having trouble figuring out is how to resume them on demand.

I tried to look into the TaskScheduler to see if it provided some alternatives to programmatically provide access to the tasks and/or force the execution. It was not clear to me if I could change the delay at runtime?

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Mark

Comment: `> need more fine grain control vs. just shutting down an endpoint programmatically` It's not clear why stopping/starting the XD source module's inbound channel adapter won't do what you need. You can use a control bus or JMX for that. What could be more "finer grained"?

Comment: The use case is as follows: you have n number of streams that are picking up data from some source - call it data from providers xyz. All these streams feed into a common uber processing stream that is composed of various streams performing common flow with dedicated by-provider transformations.  Now while the data is in flight we need to pause processing for all providers except one. Furthermore we might want to pause all and only let a particular provider's message run through for the system before we open it back up.

Comment: I'd say that `<int:aggregator>` is for you. We always can emulate the `correlationKey` to form message groups to release or wait for some particular event in face of `marker` message. From other side consider to use a new `<int:barrier>` component since version 4.2 which allows to suspend the `Thread` until the resume event: http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/whats-new.html#x4.2-barrier

Comment: Thanks - I will look into both of those.